# Can't run rollback migration because other objects depends on it

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I've been struggling for a while with migrations and literally I have no idea how to solve it. I guess this is my lack of experience with databases, but can't understand where's the issue when I have .onDelete('CASCADE'). So I'm using postgresql and knex for my project. Everything was fine with 2 tables, rollbacks worked fine until I created extra one table(balance). I can't run migrations anymore, I understand the error, but literally have no idea how to solve it. Whenever I'm running '**npx knex migrate:rollback**' I receive error: "**migration failed with error: drop table "wallet" - cannot drop table wallet because other objects depend on it**"

It looks like that I'm stuck with FK chain, not sure is it a good practice to do like I'm doing, but if you have any insights - let me know!

As I mentioned I have 3 tables now.

20220328091102_users

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
        table.increments('user_id').primary();
        table.string('username').unique().notNullable();
        table.string('password').notNullable();
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
};
```

20220328181130_wallet

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('wallet', table => {
        table.increments('wallet_id').primary();
        table.integer('user_id').unsigned();
        table.foreign('user_id').references('user_id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE');
        table.string('wallet_name').notNullable();
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    });
};
exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('wallet');
};
```

20220328181625_balance

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('balance', table => {
        table.increments('balance_id').primary();
        table.integer('wallet_id').unsigned();
        table.foreign('wallet_id').references('wallet_id').inTable('wallet').onDelete('CASCADE');
        table.string('action').enum(['increase', 'decrease']).defaultTo(null);
        table.integer('amount').defaultTo(null);
        table.integer('total_balance_new').notNullable();
        table.integer('total_balance_previous').notNullable();
        table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    });
};
exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('wallet');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't answer why dropping table with `return knex.schema.dropTable('table_name')` occurs the error, but perfectly works with `return knex.raw('DROP TABLE table_name CASCADE');` in this situation.